# UndeliverableException during Bitmap download : RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I have an observable chain as follows in my fragment. I have a spinner , which triggers a `Subject` on item selection,  and based on the selection , I'm downloading bitmaps in `Schedulers.computation()` using Picasso.

```
Disposable d =  mSpinnerSelectionSubject.switchMap(selectedItem -> Observable.fromCallable(this::getImageDetails))
          .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
          .switchMap(imageDetails -> Observable.fromCallable(() -> mPicasso.load(imageDetails.getImagePath()).get()))
          .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
          .switchMap(this::setBitmapInView)
          .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
          .switchMap(this::generateBitmaps) // this method does some opencv bitmap operation
          .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
          .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<ImageData>() {
              @Override
              public void onNext(ImageData imageData) {
                  // do something
              }

              @Override
              public void onError(Throwable e) {
                  // handle error
              }

              @Override
              public void onComplete() {
                  Timber.d("onComplete: ");
              }
          }));

mCompositeDisposable.add(d);
```

Its works fine but sometimes I get a `UndeliverableException` . I have given the stacktrace below.

```
io.reactivex.exceptions.UndeliverableException: java.io.InterruptedIOException: thread interrupted
    at io.reactivex.plugins.RxJavaPlugins.onError(RxJavaPlugins.java:367)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFromCallable.subscribeActual(ObservableFromCallable.java:48)
    at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:11442)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSwitchMap$SwitchMapObserver.onNext(ObservableSwitchMap.java:126)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.drainNormal(ObservableObserveOn.java:200)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.run(ObservableObserveOn.java:252)
    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:66)
    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:57)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:272)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
 Caused by: java.io.InterruptedIOException: thread interrupted
    at okio.Timeout.throwIfReached(Timeout.java:145)
    at okio.Okio$1.write(Okio.java:76)
    at okio.AsyncTimeout$1.write(AsyncTimeout.java:180)
    at okio.RealBufferedSink.flush(RealBufferedSink.java:224)
    at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.finishRequest(Http1Codec.java:166)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:84)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:45)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
    at com.squareup.picasso.OkHttp3Downloader.load(OkHttp3Downloader.java:91)
    at com.squareup.picasso.NetworkRequestHandler.load(NetworkRequestHandler.java:46)
    at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.hunt(BitmapHunter.java:219)
    at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.get(RequestCreator.java:429)
    at com.my.app.modules.detailscreen.DetailFragment.lambda$null$7$DetailFragment(Fragment.java:117)
```

I tried re-producing the error and what I could see is , it mainly happens If I leave the fragment while the bitmap is being downloaded.

The observable I'm adding to a `CompositeDisposable` and in the fragment 'onDestroyView' event Im calling

```
mCompositeDisposable.clear();
```

Also in the `onDestroy` event im doing

```
mCompositeDisposable.clear();
```

I'm not getting what exactly causing the crash. Hope somebody can help me. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: `works fine but sometimes I get a UndeliverableException` Can be but you have a `java.io.InterruptedIOException`.

Comment: @greenapps What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source of the exception is `Observable.fromCallable(() -> mPicasso.load(imageDetails.getImagePath()).get())`. It occurs because the scheduler it is running on sends an `Thread.interrupt()` signal when it is disposed and the `fromCallable` operator will catch the exception and signal it regardless of whether the operation has already been disposed.

To work around this, you can use `Single.create` instead, then manually catching and handling the exceptions through the `SingleEmitter.tryOnError` method.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have modified my code [like this](http://codejaw.com/roye5e). Can you verify it once please?

Comment: That looks like it would work. Personally I'd use one based on `Single` instead of `Observable` since it can produce only a value or fail, simplifying the contract.

Comment: My entire chain works with `Observable` , that's why I went for `Observable.create`. Instead should I use `Single.toObservable()`?

Comment: Internally it will end up looking almost the same, but the semantics may help if you end up replacing the code in the future.